# Computing $\langle\sin(\gamma_i)\rangle= \int_{(S^2)^N} \sin(\gamma_i)p(\Theta)dS$

Tags: integration, statistics, mathematical-modeling, biology

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral, which I know must be zero,
$$\langle\sin(\gamma_i)\rangle= \int_{(S^2)^N} \sin(\gamma_i)p(\Gamma)dS$$
Where,
$$\langle \vec{a}(\vec{r_1},...,\vec{r_N})\rangle= \int_{(\mathbb{R})^N} \vec{a}(\vec{r_1},...,\vec{r_N})p(\vec{r_1},...,\vec{r_N})dV$$
and $p(\vec{r_1},...,\vec{r_N})$ is the pdf of the configuration $(\vec{r_1},...,\vec{r_N})$.
 There are a lot of definitions here which can be found in the reference material, but they should not be needed. We also have
$$p(\Gamma)=\frac1Z \exp(\delta\sum_{j=1}^N \cos(\gamma_j))$$
Where $Z=\int_{(S^2)^N} \exp(\delta\sum_{j=1}^N \cos(\gamma_j))dS$ and $\Gamma=\{\gamma_i\}$.
Therefore
$$\langle\sin(\gamma_i)\rangle=$$
$$ \frac1Z \int_0^{2\pi} \cdots\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \cdots\int_0^{\pi} \sin(\gamma_i)\exp(\delta\sum_{j=1}^N \cos(\gamma_j))\sin(\gamma_1)d\gamma_1 \cdots \sin(\gamma_N)d\gamma_N d\phi_1\cdots d\phi_N$$

$$=\frac{(4\pi)^N}{Z} \prod_{j=1}^N \int_0^\pi \sin(\gamma_i) \sin(\gamma_j) \exp(\delta\cos( \gamma_j)) d\gamma_j$$

Now $$Z=(4\pi)^N \prod_{j=1}^N \int_0^\pi \sin(\gamma_j) \exp(\delta \cos(\gamma_j)) d\gamma_j$$
Therefore
$$\langle\sin(\gamma_i)\rangle=\frac{\int_0^\pi \sin^2(\gamma_i) \exp(\delta\cos( \gamma_i)) d\gamma_i}{\int_0^\pi \sin(\gamma_i) \exp(\delta \cos(\gamma_i)) d\gamma_i}\neq0
$$
(http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5Epi+sin%28x%29%5E2+e%5E%28cos%28x%29%29+dx)

I can't for the life of me see what's going wrong here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: With reference to the pdf file, here is the proof as to why I know this integral must be zero,

On page 10 there is the proof of: $w_n=ww_{n-1}$

$w_n=\langle \vec{t}_i \cdot \vec{t}_{i+n}\rangle=\langle \cos(\gamma_i+...+γ_{i+n-1})\rangle$

We then expand the cos term into:
$w_n=\langle \cos(γ_i)\rangle \langle\ \cos(\gamma_{i+1}+...+γ_{i+n-1})\rangle-\langle \sin(γ_i)\rangle \langle \sin(\gamma_{i+1}+...+γ_{i+n-1})\rangle$

$\Rightarrow w_n=ww_{n-1}+\langle \sin(γ_i)\rangle \langle\cdots\rangle$

$\Rightarrow \langle \sin(γ_i)\rangle=0$

Comment: What about the following remark on the second page: "Please do not disseminate these notes. They are only intended for internal use within the context of the course. This is the first version of these notes"?? Do you think your teacher will appreciate posting the file on a public site?

Comment: I believe he would be ok with using them as a reference for a question. I believe he is referring to them being used for reference material for a course he is not running, due to their incomplete nature.

Comment: @Freeman It specifically seems that your professor does not want you distributing his notes in anyway as he has written on the 2nd page.  In regards to general questions, if you want to learn how to calculate correlation functions for linear/diatomic/arbritary chain models, you ought to learn some  solid state physics & quantum mechanics.  Otherwise you will be fooling only yourself.  Without this, you shouldn't be attempting to use partition functions and solid state physics concepts without knowing the background of them

Comment: @Freeman It is illegal to post his lecture notes like this, you should remove them immediately.

Comment: If you wish to reference a portion of the notes, you should copy the relevant portion and put that in the question. This would qualify as fair use, while linking to the entire document does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how you get from:
$$ \frac1Z \int_0^{2\pi} \cdots\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \cdots\int_0^{\pi} \sin(\gamma_i)\exp(\delta\sum_{j=1}^N \cos(\gamma_j))\sin(\gamma_1)d\gamma_1 \cdots \sin(\gamma_N)d\gamma_N d\phi_1\cdots d\phi_N$$
to
$$ \frac{(4\pi)^N}{Z} \prod_{j=1}^N \int_0^\pi \sin(\gamma_i) \sin(\gamma_j) \exp(\delta\cos( \gamma_j)) d\gamma_j$$
In the first expression, $\sin(\gamma_i)$ appears once.  In the right hand side it appears $N$ times.  Shouldn't you get
$$ \frac{(4\pi)^N}{Z} \prod_{j=1}^N \int_0^\pi \sin^{1+\delta_{ij}}(\gamma_j) \exp(\delta\cos( \gamma_j)) d\gamma_j ?$$

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be $(2\pi)^N$ instead of $(4\pi)^N$?

Comment: Also, I am wondering if you stated the problem correctly.  $\langle \cdot \rangle$ usually refers to some kind of expected value.  But the way you have defined $\gamma_i$, it is always between $0$ and $\pi$.  Hence $\sin(\gamma_i) > 0$ except on a set of measure zero.  So how can $\langle \sin(\gamma_i)\rangle$ be anything other than positive?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm seeing this right, but when writing the multiple integrals you will have an integral of the type
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(\gamma_i) \exp(\delta \cos(\gamma_i))d\gamma_i$$
which is zero (it is the integral of an odd periodic function over one period). Therefore the rest of the expression is zero.

Comment: The proof above the one I am citing requires $w=\langle \cos \gamma_i \rangle=\cdots=\frac1{\delta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\delta}\log \int_0^{\pi} \sin(\gamma_i) \exp(\delta \cos(\gamma_i))d\gamma_i=\frac1{\delta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\delta}\log \frac{2\sinh(\delta)}{\delta}=L(\delta)$, this demonstrates that the integral over $\gamma_i$ must be from $0$ to $\pi$

Comment: Please explain clearly what you mean by $\langle\cdot\rangle$. in the beginning of the question you write it as an integral, then you use other formulas...

Comment: I have updated it, is it the expected value.